# section numbering including only the lowest sectionning level

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'd like to have in my document the main parts (chapter, section) not numbered, but having numbered subsections and subsubsections. I'd like that the numbers restart in each new unit.

I was trying to change the numbering by adding to preable:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

but the numbering continue in whole document and don't restart in each section, I guess it restarts after each numbered section of a higher level.

What I'd like to achive is to have in the body of document `*chapter` and `*section`; `subsubsection` always numbered and `subsection` sometimes starred, sometimes not.

Here is minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{polish}
\setotherlanguage[locale=mashriq]{arabic}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Scheherazade}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Pierwszy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Pierwszy}

\section*{Jakaś część}
\subsection{To też}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{bbb}
\subsection{I to również}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\subsubsection{dddd}

\section*{Inna część}
\subsection*{A to podpunkt}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{bbb}
\subsection*{I to}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\subsubsection{dddd}



\chapter*{Drugi}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Drugi}

\section*{Jakaś część}
\subsection*{To też}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{bbb}
\subsection*{I to również}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\subsubsection{dddd}

\section*{Inna część}
\subsection{A to podpunkt}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{bbb}
\subsection{I to}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\subsubsection{dddd}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Maybe I'm trying to achive what I wont with wrong tool. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I don't think packages like `fontspec` and `polyglossia` are relevant, you can remove them (as well as their options) from your example, so that one doesn't need `xetex` to compile the MWE.

Comment: What should happen to the `subsubsection` counter when you use `\subsection*`? Should it reset or not?

Comment: @T.Verron I could remove it if my goal was only compile the MWE, but I need this solution to compile a document where I do need `xetex`. That's why I'm keeping `fontspec` and `polyglossia` here.

Comment: @Werner Starred versions give no numbering in the output. And I would like to have subsubsections numbered...

Comment: @maria: That doesn't answer the question. What should happen to the counter associated with `\subsubsection` when you have an unnumbered (or starred) `\subsection`? Typically, using `\subsection` *would* restart the `\subsubsection` counter, while using `\subsection*` would *not* restart the `\subsubsection` counter.

Comment: @Werner It seems I misunderstood your question. When I was trying only with starred/non-starred versions, I had numbering `0.0.1` instead of `1`. And when I wanted to "swich off" the zeros (with the `renewcommad` in the preamble), the counter was not reseted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't really think this is a good idea, but the book is yours. The numbers should help readers in orienting themselves in the book.

But here's a way to do it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % this is necessary
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % this is only to provide mock text

\setmainlanguage{polish}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

%%% ADDED CODE
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname mythe#1\endcsname}
\def\mythesubsection{\thesubsection\quad}
\def\mythesubsubsection{\thesubsubsection\quad}
\let\latex@subsection\subsection
\def\subsection{\@ifstar{\refstepcounter{subsection}\latex@subsection*}{\latex@subsection}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\let\latex@l@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latex@l@chapter{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
%%% END ADDED CODE

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pierwszy}

\section{Jakaś część}
\subsection{To też}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{bbb}
\subsection{I to również}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\subsubsection{dddd}

\section{Inna część}
\subsection*{A to podpunkt}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{bbb}
\subsection*{I to}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\subsubsection{dddd}



\chapter{Drugi}

\section{Jakaś część}
\subsection*{To też}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\kant[1]

\subsubsection{bbb}
\kant[1]

\subsection*{I to również}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\kant[1]

\subsubsection{dddd}
\kant


\section{Inna część}
\subsection{A to podpunkt}
\subsubsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{bbb}
\subsection{I to}
\subsubsection{ccc}
\subsubsection{dddd}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Some explanations are in order.

1. The easiest and best documented hack is the one with `fancyhdr`, where the way the headers are defined is set. The hack consists in removing the "Chapter n" or section number bit from the headers by redefining `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`.
2. Each sectioning command from `\section` and below executes `\@seccntformat{<level>}`, where `<level>` stands for `section`, `subsection` and so on. The usual definition is

   ```
   \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
   ```

   and I redefine it as

   ```
   \def\@seccntformat#1{\csname mythe#1\endcsname}
   ```

   so `\mythesection` and so on will be executed in turn or *nothing at all* if the command is not defined. Therefore it's sufficient to define `\mythesubsection` and `\mythesubsubsection`.
3. I redefine also `\@makechapterhead`, removing the part where "Chapter n" is set.
4. `\subsection` is redefined so that the number is stepped anyway. One might prefer

   ```
   \def\subsection{%
     \@ifstar
       {\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}\latex@subsection*}
       {\latex@subsection}}
   ```

   so that the subsection number is not stepped, but only the subsubsection counter is reset to 0.
5. Finally `\l@chapter` is modified so that `\numberline` will ignore its argument and the chapter number will not appear in the table of contents.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot, it works now exactly how I wanted! As for letting main parts of document unnumbered, I agree with you, but here I have some special thing to do and it would really be more clear like that.