# Numbering to start from section not chapter

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, chapters

I want chapters not to have any numbers (both in the text and in the table of contents) and the numbering in each section to start from 1. For example (both in text and toc):

```
Introduction
1 Section
1.1 Subsection
2 Section

Literature Review
1 Section
1.1 Subsection
2 Section
```

The default behavior is:

```
Chapter 1 Introduction
1.1 Section
1.1.1 Subsection
1.2 Section

Chapter 2 Literature Review
2.1 Section
2.1.1 Subsection
2.2 Section
```

The reason why I am after achieving this effect is:

- Because the document I am writing is lengthy, I need to break it into many parts, hence I really need the `subsubsection`s to be numbered (in the text and toc).
- Again because of its length, I think the chapters have a more substantial role in separating the text, therefore having the section numbers to start sharp at 1 instead of x.1 would be a good idea.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85646/4427) is an answer to a very similar question, which can adapted to your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility, using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) duo:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0em]{\addvspace{10pt}\bfseries}
  {}{}{\titlerule*[1000pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section Two}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section Two}

\end{document}
```

The ToC:

[image]

The initial page of the first chapter:

[image]

To have the subsubsections numbered you need to add to the preamble

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

and to include them in the ToC,

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

You will also probably need to redefine `\thefigure` and `\thetable` to suppress the chapter numbering.